# Why does StringBuilder.Equals return "true" in this case?

Tags: c#, string, equals, stringbuilder, equals-operator

I have a small issue comparing two StringBuilders in C# (XNA).

```
StringBuilder sb1;
StringBuilder sb2;
```

Both are initialized in different sections of my code. A simple Console.WriteLine shows that they contain the same text. However, the following is false:

```
sb1.Equals(sb2); // This is false
```

and yet the following is true

```
sb1.ToString().Equals(sb2.ToString); // This is true
```

How can this occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two overloads of `Equals` on `StringBuilder` which can do slightly unexpected things.

The `Equals(Object)` overload is inherited from Object and compares references.

The `Equals(StringBuilder)` overload compares **content, Capacity, and MaxCapacity**.

You seem to be calling the second of these two overloads.

Since StringBuilder will dynamically expand its capacity, the result of comparing two StringBuilder instances depends on the exact sequence of operations (e.g. Append, Replace, Remove, etc.) performed on each one.

For example this give the result you describe:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(), sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb1.Append("something").Append('1', 100).Replace("1", "");
sb2.Append("something");
Console.WriteLine(sb1.Equals(sb2)); // False
Console.WriteLine(sb1.ToString().Equals(sb2.ToString())); // True
```

There doesn't seem to be built-in way to only compare the content but you can easily write your own comparison if you don't want to allocate strings when comparing:

```
public static bool Equals(StrinBuilder left, StringBuilder right)
{
    if (left.Length != right.Length)
        return false;

    int length = left.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (left[i] != right[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! To me it is quite unexpected that capacity and maxCapacity are used in "Equals" but it certainly explains why the second overload is not working as expected (content only).

Answer (score 7):

Because `string` class overrides `Equals` method and therefore *strings* are compared by values instead of references.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

> Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references.

It talks about `==` and `!=` operators but they are actually calling `string.Equals` and it compares strings by values.

Comment: Of great, this explains it. Is there a way to use StringBuilders to compare their values directly?

Comment: @pad_ares you can't override StringBuilder.Equals but  you can always implement your own method. And then use it instead of StringBuilder.Equals

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do?  Are you trying to determine whether two `StringBuilder` instances contain the same text?  If so then you already have a way to do that, i.e. the second code snippet you posted yourself.  You could even write an extension method so that you could call it on an instance.  Remember that the point of a `StringBuilder` is to build a `String` so comparing contents is outside of their area of expertise.

Comment: `StringBuilder` does not override Equals but it does provide an overload that takes another `StringBuilder`. That overload compares content. It is not clear why that overload would not be called in this case.